# О чем говорит ошибка NotImplementedError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Работаю с гемом, известным только в довольно узком круге.
И получаю ошибку NotImplementedError

Когда и почему она возникает?

Comment: Скорее всего, где то в коде гема есть вызов этого исключения Такое добавляют, например, в методы классов, что необходимо реализовать при наследовании

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Обычно такую ошибку бросают в наследуемом методе интерфейса, который нужно переопределить. Например - у вас есть базовый класс

```
class BaseService
  def call
    raise NotImplementedError
  end
end
```

Допустим вы хотите создать другой сервис и использовать этот класс в кач-ве базового

```
class FooService < BaseService
end
```

При вызове `FooService.new.call` вы получите `NotImplementedError`, что просигнализирует о том, что разработчик базового класса напоминает вам определить метод call.

Обычно это делают не с методом call, а с какими-нибудь приватными методами, которые метод call использует в базовом классе, но которые должны отличаться от наследника к наследнику.